# DOMPDF with Print module printing a black background

Tags: files

I have downloaded the print module and tested it with TCPDF, but had a hard time styling things. I then decided to use DOMPDF. It picks up the `print.tpl.php` from the site/themes/templates folder, and the styling from site/modules/print/css/ folder from `print.css`. All good so far.

However, when I try to print a PDF, I get a black background, and I have tried to get rid of by giving the body a background, but to no avail.

Comment: Do you see a black background even when you try to to print/ it or only using printpdf/

Comment: No, there is no black background when I print/nid, only with printpdf/nid.